# SQLCMD into SQL server 2000

Tags: sql

Can you use sqlcmd to query a sql server 2000 database? and if so where is the smallest download of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can and it is on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090412065213/http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b33d2c78-1059-4ce2-b80d-2343c099bcb4)

Comment: The link is dead now. Thanks Microsoft!